# Using alternate rating laptop charger

Tags: laptop, battery, voltage, charger, rating

I am using Sony Vaio and laptop charger burned its rating was 19.5V-3.9A, i am trying to find the same model but I have been only been able to find one with the rating 19.5V-4.7A. Can I use this, any pro's and cons. FYI my battery has already worn out!

Comment: Make sure the polarity is also the same (e.g., center pin positive), or else you'll let the smoke out and the laptop won't work any more. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No problem - your notebook will only draw the required amount of current from the adapter.

It is dangerous when you have a lower current rating on your adapter, as the notebook will draw more than what the adapter can give, thus causing potential fire hazards, or your notebook won't charge, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As long as current rating is higher than original one, there is no cons. Device will use as much current as it needs (or it was designed to).