# can i use a laptop charger with same input voltage but differen input amperage?

Tags: lenovo-laptop, charger

My original laptop charger is not working, can i use a new charger ? whose input 100-240v-2.4a (2.4a) 50-60hz and output 20v(20v)== 4.5a(4.5a). My  original cahrger input 100-240v~1.7a 50-60hz and output 20v(20v) == 3.24a(3.24a).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a 20V 4.51A power supply be used with a computer that requires a 19V 3.42A power supply?](http://superuser.com/questions/245715/can-a-20v-4-51a-power-supply-be-used-with-a-computer-that-requires-a-19v-3-42a-p)

Comment: The input amp rating is easily explained by the output amp rating.  Since the new charger has about 40% more output capability than your old charger, it stands to reason that its input requirements would also increase in a similar proportion (assuming similar efficiency).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I safely charge my laptop with a non-standard, third-party charger?](http://superuser.com/questions/32372/can-i-safely-charge-my-laptop-with-a-non-standard-third-party-charger)

Comment: Also see: http://superuser.com/questions/410379/using-alternate-rating-laptop-charger and http://superuser.com/questions/495180/will-my-laptop-be-ok-with-this-different-laptop-charger

Comment: As long the voltage match and you have the same or more amps it should be fine.

Comment: I learned that when the amps don't match either the brick gets too hot or can wear out too quickly. Yes it will work, but it could be dangarous.

Answer (score 0):

Your *best* bet is always to replace it with an identical device from the original equipment manufacturer.

However, the entire point of the power brick that comes with a laptop is to convert wall power into something the device can use. As long as the *output* voltage matches, and the amperage is sufficient, it should work fine.

Just make sure to check the connector fit and polarity. You don't want a loose connector (it could spark) and you *really* don't want to reverse the polarity.